# Making single section title in toc bold

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, bold

I am writing a paper and I need to have the introduction (Einleitung), conclusion(Schluss), list of figures and list of tables to be bold. Meaning all unnumbered entires.
Just like the Bibliography (Literaturverzeichnis).
But I didn't find a solution to change single titles only for the whole toc.
Also list of figures and list of tables aren't showing in the toc.
Does someone know a solution to the problems? I would be happy for help. Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[twoside, parskip=half, 12pt, egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles]{scrreprt}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}} %entfernugn der null bei der numerierung
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}

\title{xxx}
\author{xxx}
\date{xxx}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\section*{Einleitung}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Einleitung}

\section{Definition Big Data}

That's a text \cite{text}.

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{Images}
\caption{And that's an Image}
\label{fig:Image}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{tblr}{
    colspec = {|l|l|l|},
  } \hline
   Item    & Qty & Unit \\ \hline
 Widget  & 1 & 199.99 \\
 Gadget & 2 & 399.933 \\
 Cable & 3 & 19.99 \\ \hline
    \end{tblr}
\caption{And that's a table}

\end{table}


\section{Cambridge Analytica} 
\section{Schweiz}
\section*{Schluss}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Schluss}


\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{Bibliography.bib}
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\end{document}
```

[image: Rendering of example's table of content]

Comment: So all unnumbered entries should be bold? Please add a short but compilable  test document. We can't compile your code as we don't have access to all your included files.

Comment: The bibliography, list of tables and the list of figures are unnumbered chapters. If "Einleitung" and "Schluss" should use the same format use `\addchap{Einleitung}` and `\addchap{Schluss}`.

Answer (score 4):

Your example is a little bit strange, because you are using class `scrreprt`, but it seems you don't want to use `\chapter`. So IMHO using `scrartcl` would be the better choice. In this case the default for section entries to the TOC is already bold. So:

```
\documentclass[%
twoside, parskip=half, 12pt, egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles,
%headings=normal,% Maybe you want to have smaller headings
]{scrartcl}% It seems you are not using \chapter, so this would be the better class.
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}} %entfernugn der null bei der numerierung
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
%\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}% This package is not recommended
                                             % with scrreprt or scrarcl. You
                                             % should use options like
                                             % bibliography=totoc instead

\title{xxx}
\author{xxx}
\date{xxx}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\addsec{Einleitung}

\section{Definition Big Data}

That's a text \cite{text}.

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \caption{And that's an Image}
  \label{fig:Image}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{tblr}{
    colspec = {|l|l|l|},
  } \hline
   Item    & Qty & Unit \\ \hline
   Widget  & 1 & 199.99 \\
   Gadget & 2 & 399.933 \\
   Cable & 3 & 19.99 \\ \hline
 \end{tblr}
 \caption{And that's a table}
\end{table}


\section{Cambridge Analytica} 
\section{Schweiz}
\addsec{Schluss}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{Bibliography.bib}
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\end{document}
```

Would already make the not numbered section entries bold (but also the numbered). If you really do not want the numbered section entries bold and if you also want to remove the distance before section entries, you could use:

```
\documentclass[%
twoside, parskip=half, 12pt, egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles,
%headings=normal,% Maybe you want to have smaller headings
]{scrartcl}% It seems you are not using \chapter, so this would be the better class.
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}} %entfernugn der null bei der numerierung
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
%\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}% This package is not recommended
                                             % with scrreprt or scrarcl. You
                                             % should use options like
                                             % bibliography=totoc instead

\title{xxx}
\author{xxx}
\date{xxx}

\renewcommand*{\addsectiontocentry}[2]{%
  \IfArgIsEmpty{#1}{% no number
    \addtocentrydefault{section}{#1}{\bfseries #2}% make if bold
  }{%
    \addtocentrydefault{section}{#1}{#2}% this is the original definition
  }%
}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[entryformat=\textmd,beforeskip=0pt]{section}{section}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\addsec{Einleitung}

\section{Definition Big Data}

That's a text \cite{text}.

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \caption{And that's an Image}
  \label{fig:Image}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{tblr}{
    colspec = {|l|l|l|},
  } \hline
   Item    & Qty & Unit \\ \hline
   Widget  & 1 & 199.99 \\
   Gadget & 2 & 399.933 \\
   Cable & 3 & 19.99 \\ \hline
 \end{tblr}
 \caption{And that's a table}
\end{table}


\section{Cambridge Analytica} 
\section{Schweiz}
\addsec{Schluss}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{Bibliography.bib}
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\end{document}
```

[image: using scrartcl]

However, if you insist in using `scrreprt` without `\chapter`, you can still do so:

```
\documentclass[%
twoside, parskip=half, 12pt, egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles,
%headings=normal,% Maybe you want to have smaller headings
]{scrreprt}% It seems you are not using \chapter, so this would be the better class.
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}} %entfernugn der null bei der numerierung
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
%\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}% This package is not recommended
                                             % with scrreprt or scrarcl. You
                                             % should use options like
                                             % bibliography=totoc instead

\title{xxx}
\author{xxx}
\date{xxx}

\renewcommand*{\addsectiontocentry}[2]{%
  \IfArgIsEmpty{#1}{% no number
    \addtocentrydefault{section}{#1}{\bfseries #2}% make if bold
  }{%
    \addtocentrydefault{section}{#1}{#2}% this is the original definition
  }%
}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[counterwithout=chapter,
  tocentryformat=\textmd,tocbeforeskip=0pt]{section}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\addsec{Einleitung}

\section{Definition Big Data}

That's a text \cite{text}.

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \caption{And that's an Image}
  \label{fig:Image}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{tblr}{
    colspec = {|l|l|l|},
  } \hline
   Item    & Qty & Unit \\ \hline
   Widget  & 1 & 199.99 \\
   Gadget & 2 & 399.933 \\
   Cable & 3 & 19.99 \\ \hline
 \end{tblr}
 \caption{And that's a table}
\end{table}


\section{Cambridge Analytica} 
\section{Schweiz}
\addsec{Schluss}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{Bibliography.bib}
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\end{document}
```

[image: with scrreprt]

However, in this case, I would suggest to also add option `tocentryindent=0pt` to `\RedeclareSectionCommand`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside, parskip=half, 12pt, egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles]{scrreprt}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}} %entfernugn der null bei der numerierung
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}
%\usepackage{hyperref} <-- uncomment it for klicable TOC

\title{xxx}
\author{xxx}
\date{xxx}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\clearpage

\section*{Einleitung}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\textbf{Einleitung}}

\section{Definition Big Data}

That's a text \cite{text}.
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{And that's an Image}
\label{fig:Image}
\end{figure}

\begin{table} 
\begin{tabular}{lrr}
 Item    & Qty & Unit \$  \\
 Widget  & 1 & 199.99 \\
 Gadget & 2 & 399.933 \\
 Cable & 3 & 19.99 \\
\end{tabular}
\caption{And that's a table}
\end{table}


\section{Cambridge Analytica} 
\section{Schweiz}
\section*{Schluss}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\textbf{Schluss}}


\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{Bibliography.bib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yeah, like that. Thank you very much :))
And I found out how to include the lof an lot so it is shown like the bibliography.
One has to add listof=totoc in \documentclass[]

Comment: @IAmLost fine, You are wellcome!